# Copy bitmap header

Tags: bitmap, bmp

I have made this strtuctre

```
 typedef struct
    {
        short int type;
        int taille;
        short int reserved;
        int offst;
        int header_size;
        int width;
        int height;
        short int plans;
        short int bitperpixel;
        int compression;
        int bmptaille;
        int Hresolu;
        int Vresolu;
        int nbcouleurs;
        int nbcouleursimp;
    } info_header;
```

then I have open the file and verify if it's well open with this function

```
void ouverture_file( FILE * fichier1)
{
    if (fichier1==NULL)
    printf("probleme ouverture fichier\n");
    else
    printf("fichier est bien ouvert\n");
}
```

(this code down is in main )

```
FILE* fichier=NULL;
    fichier= fopen("lena.bmp","rb+");
    ouverture_file(fichier);
    info_header * bmpheader=NULL;
```

now I want to know how could i copy the header into the infoheader structure then print the first octet where the pixels begins.

Comment: Copy? You must mean `fread`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938807/trouble-reading-bmp-header-file-properly for complete code. All you need to immediately position to the pixel offset is to fseek to `info_header.offst`.